# Java Swing: prevent Components to update enabled state until I tell them to

Tags: java, swing

I have an extensive Gui with many components in it. There is a `updateEnable()` methods that updates the enable state of all the components based on some configuration.

I basically first set their enable state to true and then disable some of them (based on the configuration):

```
private void updateEnable() {
  enableAllRec(panel, true);
  // disable some components
}

private void enableAllRec(Container root, boolean b) {
  if (root == null) return;
  for (Component c : root.getComponents()) {
    c.setEnabled(b);
    if (c instanceof Container) enableAllRec((Container) c, b);
  }
}
```

The reason I do it like that is that some of the components are not stored as member variables and I don't have access to them. They however can change their state because I initialized some of them like this (for example):

```
final JLabel exampleLabel = new JLabel("yoink");
final JCheckBox exampleCheckBox = new JCheckBox("boing");
exampleCheckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    exampleLabel.setEnable(exampleCheckBox.isSelected());
  }
});
```

Now my problem is the following: When I call `updateEnable()`, some of the (stored) Components may flicker because they are enabled and then disabled again after some time. I would like to prevent that. My idea is to somehow prevent the GUI from refreshing until the very end of `updateEnable()` and then perform an `updateUI()`. But this is not very elegant AND I have no idea how to prevent the GUI from updating.

Am I missing a very elegant alternative solution for this problem?

Thanks a lot,
Stefan

Comment: you can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065456/prevent-java-from-repainting-the-content-of-a-jpanel-while-updating).

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. Although an idea for a more elegant way came to my mind. I will post an answer if it works well.

Comment: Ok, I just posted my current solution and accepted it as it seems to work fine for me. mgarins caching idea is also a possibility although I don't like to create a Map containing every Component of my gui. My approach only creates a set of the special cases which I think is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my approach seems to work. I just extended the `enableAllRec(Container root, boolean b)`to include some exclusions:

```
private void enableAllRec(Container root, boolean defaultState, Set<Component> disableList, Set<Component> enableList) {
  if (root == null) return;
  for (Component c : root.getComponents()) {
    if (disableList != null && disableList.contains(c)) {
      c.setEnabled(false);
      disableList.remove(c);
    } else if (enableList != null && enableList.contains(c)) {
      c.setEnabled(true);
      enableList.remove(c);
    } else c.setEnabled(defaultState);
    if (c instanceof Container) enableAllRec((Container) c, defaultState, disableList, enableList);
  }
}
```

This way, I can determen all the components that I want to have enabled/disabled for sure, add them to their corresponding sets and thenn call the enableAllRec. Example:

```
Set<Component> enableList = new HashSet<Component>();
enableList.add(searchFreqButton);
enableList.add(advMeasButton);
enableAllRec(configPanel, false, null, enableList);
```

Obviously, this is not ideal for large sets, but it is sufficient for my needs (arround 800 Components and the sets contain no more than arround 20-30 components). I suspect this method to easily handle larger sets as well.

In the above example, it makes no sense to introduce a disableList (as all components will be disabled by default anyway). So depending on the default value, one can leave out the corresponding set. This should preferably be done in `enableAllRec()` of course.

Answer (score 1):

In case your components might be enabled/disabled a few times in a row due to some logical changes and calculations - you should perform that calculation before applying some of the changes to visual components. In that case you will change components state straight into final one.

Comment: The problem here is, that I don't have access to some of them except through `Container.getComponents()`.

Comment: Than either make it in two runs or cache final states into some map like Map<Component,Boolean> and after that run through that map setting final values into setEnabled method of the components.

Comment: The caching idea would be nice too although it would create a Map of all my components, which i think is not neccessary, because most of them are just fine with the `enableAllRec()` default set...