# How to set a GUI non-visible within the constructor?

Tags: java, swing, constructor, visibility

I have a swing GUI class `Foo` and in the constructor of `Foo` class, I load some values from the databases. Based on the returning values from database, I can say whether this GUI should be visible or not. However, when I say, `this.setVisible(false);` inside the constructor of this GUI class, it has no effect because object creation is not completed.

How can I complete this task without user realizing the transition (disappearing of the GUI)?

Comment: Loading database in constructor is bad idea. After invoking this `setVisible(false)`, components are not visible in window.

Comment: setVisible(false) should go before you start reading the database. Thus, it would be not visible till proven otherwise(conditional that responds based on database)

Comment: @DarkV1 I tried but It is still visible even if I say, setVisible(false)

Comment: @Satya This is a very old system. It is not easy to change the structure of it. Because of this reason, I am forced to load these data in the constructor. Based on these values, the GUI is dynamically created.

Comment: *"It is not easy to change the structure of it."* - And it will be even harder for the next (poor) guy if you do this kind of thing!

Comment: I would make the constructor accept a `ResultSet`. In this scenario, other code has already made the decision as to whether to construct the frame.

Comment: @AndrewThompson There is a main GUI and a Panel. I am now working on this panel and cannot change the main gui. I should make everything within this class without touching the main GUI.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065456/prevent-java-from-repainting-the-content-of-a-jpanel-while-updating
Avoid the repaint?...
Since it's a panel it will be visible immediately, except when you avoid the repaint...

Comment: @StephenC You are right but it is 10 years old software. I cannot save it from drowning or ?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you should be striving to improve the structure / quality of the code, even if that means a LOT more work for you.  If the product is drowning / drowned ... then start again.  (But I suspect that you are exaggerating somewhat.)  Either way, look up the phrase "technical debt" in Google.

Comment: @StephenC I read something about "technical debt" and that describes my situation :) I am now junior and I will learn. Thanks again .

Comment: @StephenC That costed time but I have paid my "technical debt" and changed the structure. Now, I am getting data from parent and everything is now more stable than before. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I set a timer, which checks every 500 miliseconds if it is still in constructor. I put an flag at the end of the constructor. When the everything is done in constructor, the timer detects it and set the Gui non-visible and the timer works for 15 seconds, which is more than enough for the object creation and stops itself.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt here with your own solution. I think the Timer is a little bit out of scope :S
Why don't you aim for something more Listener-related? Like adding the panel to the view WHEN is is fully constructed? :S Or broadcast an event instead of a timer?

Comment: @m4mbax The problem with listener was that the user sees the transition. I mean, at the beginning, there was a panel but in less than a second, the panel disappeared. Nevertheless, that did not look good. I know that my solution is not elegant but it solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try invokeLater that is just delaying the execution of a block of codes inside its run method.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
      public void run()
      {
        yourFrame.setVisible(false);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I tried a similar way with "ScheduledExecutorService". I think they are working similarly. However, sometimes the user sees the GUI disappear, which is not nice.

Comment: Why would you have to HIDE it in first place? AFAIK it only SHOWS when you set it visible. Maybe the OP has some error in his constructor... :S

Comment: Nvm, did see the comment of Panel, which makes JFrame.setVisible obsolete and hence your answer, I guess.